# In how much project management should a programmer be involved?

Tags: project-management, team-role

Given that there is no hierarchy in my poject team, i.e. customer liason, project manager, architecture consultant, developers are just different roles. Everyone listens to everybody, and we move forward by agreement not by executive command. We're working on a new product and the atmosphere is very positive.

I previously worked alone, so am used to doing all project management by myself in conjunction to coding. Now that I have a team, which aspects of project management should I keep doing, and which should be done by the others?

My current worry, is that I'm spending too much time in meetings and doing high-level things(budget, product definition, customer analysis), and I want to refocus on coding, without losing the direct influence on making project decisions that I have now.

Particularly later during the project, how much % of my time should I expect to be able to code, and how much effort should I continue to spend on project management?

(In development efforts, I currently have 95% of my work time allocated, but if I spend 5-10 hours in meetings per week that will bring me down to 60%-70% of my work time available for coding, which translates to slower product development, but perhaps more aligned project management. I'm not sure if that's a good or bad trade-off.)

Comment: I am voting to close the question because the answers are specific to the individual's circumstances and subjective i.e. opinion based. Having said that, your noncoding activities are complementary and essential to giving your coding direction, and you shortchange them at your own risk. These activities are non-negotiable and if you don't want to do them, then you have to find someone on your team to do them. You know yourself, you know your colleagues, you know your projects. We don't. The decision whether to farm out and how much to farm out is all yours.

Comment: I you know you are going to be in meetings that percentage of time, do not allow the planning process to project you at 95% coding. Even if you do nothing but code, projections should be no more than 80% becasue there needs to be time allowed for vacation and sick leave, jury duty, required admin work etc. It is irresponsible to project anyone at 95%.